# Laravel users cannot login and only admins can login

Tags: laravel

in laravel I can login with Admin accounts no issue, but when I login with any user account It doesnt login and doesnt give any error only the login page refreshes and thats it without giving any single error, yes I checked Chrome inspect and HttpRequest and nothing happens,
also check MySQL database nothing wrong with it nor it does give error.

LoginController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

RedirectIfAuthenticated

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

this is the other LoginController

class LoginController extends Controller {

```
private $Administrator;

function __construct(Administrator $administrator) {
    $this->Administrator = $administrator;
}

public function index(){
    if(Auth::check()) return redirect('/dashboard');

    return view('index.login');
}

public function login(Request $request){

    if(Auth::check()) redirect('/dashboard');

    $Username = $request->input('username');
    $Password = $request->input('password');

    $Admin = $this->Administrator->checkAuthenticate($Username,$Password);

    if($Admin){
        Auth::loginUsingId($Admin->id, true);
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }

    return redirect('/login');
}

public function logout(){

    if(Auth::check()){
        Auth::logout();
    }

    return redirect('/login');
}
```

}

Comment: did debug in your controller where it request first ?

Comment: Yes and nothing came....

Comment: share some code like your route and middleware if you are using any ?

Comment: kindly check post again I edited the codes for login and middleware

Comment: what it difference between admin and other user ?

Comment: its a school project, student login and teachers and managers login but all of these wont login except Admins

Comment: Check post again I posted another login controller which contains admin login

Comment: you did not call any method lik `attemp` for other user.

Comment: what to implement exactly? and can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

`if(Auth::check()) redirect('/dashboard');`

This is the only auth check that a regular user would pass, and you don't return the redirect so the regular users continue on through the rest of the function where they get checked to see if they're an admin, which they aren't.